# Loading old results for Data reprocessing

Tags: qiskit

I want to process some old data again. How do I load old data retrieved from IBM-Q into a new program? I've downloaded the relevant .json file, but I don't know how to  use it like I would have a new data.

Comment: Hi @Rune. Can you include a bit more information about the data that you are trying to process again? Is it the data from several shots of measurements in a quantum circuit? And where did you obtain the json file that you downloaded?

Comment: Hi @eqb. The dataset is downloaded from the "results" page on the IBM q page. The data is from a variation on a T_1 test, and thus consists of 75 circuits. we need the counts from each of these. I know this can be done manually or otherwise by directly reading the .json file. I was however wondering wherether there existed a command in qiskit that would load a downloaded result file/string as if it was new

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, I think it is a duplicate of this one: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/7117/access-results-from-an-experiment-without-having-to-run-the-script-again

Comment: That's just it @dlyongemallo! thanks!